# failed to insert data from csv file to oracle using python

Tags: python, oracle, csv

I intend to insert data in a csv file row by row into oracle database using Python & Oracle connector,
yet for text that are too long, I got an error

> ORA-01704: string literal too long

The code is as follows:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime

with open(path-to-csv-file) as f:
    reader=csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        today = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())

        if len(row['answer']) < 2000: 

            ###[ The query in this part works]###  

            sqlquery="INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('%s','%s')" %(row['answer'],today)
            cur.execute(sqlquery)

        else: 

            ###[ The query below got and error ORA-01704: string literal too long]###

            sqlquery="INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('%s','%s')" %(row['answer'],today)
            cur.execute(sqlquery)
```

I have searched on stackoverflow and tried to set the column name TEST1 to bigger size when the len(row["answer"])  is over 2000 
with

```
cur.setinputsizes(TEST1 = cx_Oracle.CLOB)
```

Yet apparently it does not work since the query form is different.

When running in the else part:

```
        else: 
            sqlquery="INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('%s','%s')" %(row['answer'],today)
            cur.setinputsizes(TEST1 = cx_Oracle.CLOB)
            cur.execute(sqlquery)
```

> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

was returned

Also, I have tried to declare the variable to varchar2 to solve this problem, but in vain.
If anyone has a better idea with this issue, your help would be much much appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you got ORA-1036 because your `sqlquery` just have not any variable. You're trying to set up TEST1 variable but where is it in your code? With variables your code should look like `INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (:TEST1, :TEST2)`; instead of this you're giving nice ability for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

About the better idea... As for me, there is no reason to make bad copy of existing decision. I'd just use [Oracle SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm) which can load csv files too.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your answer and this resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found this... the cx_Oracle library provide the [LOB object](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lob.html?highlight=clob#lob-objects) to write CLOB object in Oracle.
Read [this one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-transactions-lobs-089563.html), but it was for the 2.X.